# Statistical significance test for ranked data

Tags: statistics, usage-statistics, statistical-test

I have a list of rankings in the following format:

```
  Item  | Score | Rank
  item1 |  0.97 | 6
  item2 |  0.53 | 4
  item3 |  0.05 | 1
  item4 |  0.68 | 5
  item5 |  0.10 | 2
  item6 |  0.29 | 3
```

I want to determine whether the difference between each two pair of ranked items is significant given the scores. What statistical test should I conduct? Thank you!